# how do I update regular expression with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm having a problem with regular expression for updating. You see I'm trying to update from:

```
011013092949@boxyAa9ealA949ervice49.com
211013092923@bxod.com
343232303923@dony.com
```

To the result that I want to see something like this:

```
011013092949@boxy.com
211013092923@boxy.com
343232303923@boxy.com
```

I've tried that update procedure like this and it didn't work at all.

```
update dbo.boxy_Membership   
 set Email  like =('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]   
 [0-9]@boxy.com%')
 where Email like('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%')
 and Email  not like ('%@boxy.com')
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The `dbo.` suggests probably MS SQL Server.

Comment: What did the procedure look like before you updated it?

Comment: I'm using sql as a database and I'm having problem with regular expression.

Comment: like does not invoke regular expression in MSSQL, just wildcard matching. - But that's OK, as Goat CO's answer shows you don't need regexp for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Email` value with string manipulation:

```
update dbo.boxy_Membership   
set Email  = LEFT(Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email)-1)+'boxy.com'
 where Email LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%'
   and Email  not like ('%@boxy.com')
```

This could be further simplified if the number of digits before the `@` is constant, but based on your `WHERE` criteria that isn't clear:

```
update dbo.boxy_Membership   
set Email  = LEFT(Email,12)+'boxy.com'
 where Email LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%'      
   and Email  not like ('%@boxy.com')
```

Comment: There are 12 digits in OP's where and in the examples given.

Comment: @Taemyr The criteria in the `WHERE` clause starts with a wildcard, so I didn't want to assume it was always 12 and nothing preceding.

Comment: Fair enough, but your answer allows 11 digits.  And requires 11 digits to work correctly in the simplified version.

Comment: In fact in the simplified version the leading wildcard in the where condition should be removed, to prevent "1234567890123@example.com" to become "123456789012boxy.com" or "1234567890123boxy.com"

Answer (score 0):

I would replace everything after the `@` character with `@boxy.com` provided there are no other valid email servers.

```
create table _temp (test varchar(50))

insert into _temp values('011013092949@boxyAa9ealA949ervice49.com')
insert into _temp values('211013092923@bxod.com')
insert into _temp values('343232303923@dony.com')

select replace(test, SUBSTRING(test, charindex('@', test)+1, 40), 'boxy.com') from _temp

drop table _temp
```